# Joining two datasets using javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, dataset, javascript-objects

I have two datasets that look like this:

```
var gatePos = [ 
    { gate: 1, x: 1177, y: 200 },
    { gate: 2, x: 1109, y: 200 },
    { gate: 3, x: 1042, y: 200 },
    { gate: 4, x: 975, y: 200 },
    { gate: 5, x: 908, y: 200 },
    { gate: 6, x: 842, y: 200 },
    { gate: 7, x: 774, y: 200 },
    { gate: 8, x: 708, y: 200 },
    { gate: 9, x: 641, y: 200 },
    { gate: 10, x: 578, y: 200 }
 ];
```

and

```
[
  {
    "gate": "8B",
    "value": 126
  },
  {
    "gate": "9B",
    "value": 268
  },
  {
    "gate": "10B",
    "value": 91
  },
  {
    "gate": "21B",
    "value": 9
  },
  {
    "gate": "24B",
    "value": 1
  },
  {
    "gate": "JC",
    "value": 48352
  },
  {
    "gate": "LOCALISER",
    "value": 22
  },
  {
    "gate": 1,
    "value": 34351
  },
  {
    "gate": 2,
    "value": 37855
  },
  {
    "gate": 3,
    "value": 38462
  },
  {
    "gate": 4,
    "value": 38126
  },
  {
    "gate": 5,
    "value": 40089
  }

,
  {
    "gate": 6,
    "value": 39295
  },
  {
    "gate": 7,
    "value": 36581
  },
  {
    "gate": 8,
    "value": 33908
  },
  {
    "gate": 9,
    "value": 31187
  },
  {
    "gate": 10,
    "value": 22915
  },
  {
    "gate": 11,
    "value": 5164
  },
  {
    "gate": 12,
    "value": 9533
  },
  {
    "gate": 13,
    "value": 6454
  },
  {
    "gate": 14,
    "value": 5003
  },
  {
    "gate": 15,
    "value": 1
  },
  {
    "gate": 21,
    "value": 19804
  },
  {
    "gate": 22,
    "value": 21239
  },
  {
    "gate": 23,
    "value": 17779
  },
  {
    "gate": 24,
    "value": 15213
  },
  {
    "gate": "-",
    "value": 37562
  }
]
```

They have "Gate" as the key.
I wish to "Left join" in SQL terms my datasets, and have an output like so:

```
[{ gate: 1, x: 100, y: 200, value: 999 },
{ gate: 2, x: 150, y: 200, value: 1000}] 
... etc
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction to achieve this? I'm using d3.js mainly but I understand it doesn't have support for this type of thing so I would like to achieve in standard js, even if you can give me some terms to search or something would be a massive help.

If you are not familiar with SQL's left join, I would like my new array to contain ALL values from var gatePos but ONLY THE MATCHING values from the second dataset.

Comment: what is the join condition?

Comment: For those who don't know about _SQL's Left Join_, care to explain!

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir sorry, I have made an edit to explain

Comment: @Waller Can you recheck the values. `gate: 1` for example should have the value `34351` not `999`

Comment: Apologies.. I have corrected my code. Can you check my answer now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could mimic `left outer join` with a function and a hash table for item with same join key.

```js
var gatePos = [{ gate: 1, x: 1177, y: 200 }, { gate: 2, x: 1109, y: 200 }, { gate: 3, x: 1042, y: 200 }, { gate: 4, x: 975, y: 200 }, { gate: 5, x: 908, y: 200 }, { gate: 6, x: 842, y: 200 }, { gate: 7, x: 774, y: 200 }, { gate: 8, x: 708, y: 200 }, { gate: 9, x: 641, y: 200 }, { gate: 10, x: 578, y: 200 }],
    gateValues = [{ gate: "8B", value: 126 }, { gate: "9B", value: 268 }, { gate: "10B", value: 91 }, { gate: "21B", value: 9 }, { gate: "24B", value: 1 }, { gate: "JC", value: 48352 }, { gate: "LOCALISER", value: 22 }, { gate: 1, value: 34351 }, { gate: 2, value: 37855 }, { gate: 3, value: 38462 }, { gate: 4, value: 38126 }, { gate: 5, value: 40089 }, { gate: 6, value: 39295 }, { gate: 7, value: 36581 }, { gate: 8, value: 33908 }, { gate: 9, value: 31187 }, { gate: 10, value: 22915 }, { gate: 11, value: 5164 }, { gate: 12, value: 9533 }, { gate: 13, value: 6454 }, { gate: 14, value: 5003 }, { gate: 15, value: 1 }, { gate: 21, value: 19804 }, { gate: 22, value: 21239 }, { gate: 23, value: 17779 }, { gate: 24, value: 15213 }, { gate: "-", value: 37562 }],
    result = function (left, right, on, key) {
        var hash = Object.create(null),
            result = left.map(function (o) {
                return hash[o[on]] = Object.assign({}, o);
            });
        right.forEach(function (o) {
            if (hash[o[on]]) {
                hash[o[on]][key] = o[key];
            }
        });
        return result;
    }(gatePos, gateValues, 'gate', 'value');

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Check if this code works for you:

```
var gatePos = [{ gate: 1, x: 1177, y: 200 },{ gate: 2, x: 1109, y: 200 },{ gate: 3, x: 1042, y: 200 },{ gate: 4, x: 975, y: 200 },{ gate: 5, x: 908, y: 200 },{ gate: 6, x: 842, y: 200 },{ gate: 7, x: 774, y: 200 },{ gate: 8, x: 708, y: 200 },{ gate: 9, x: 641, y: 200 },{ gate: 10, x: 578, y: 200 }];
var gatePosValue = [{"gate":"8B","value":126},{"gate":"9B","value":268},{"gate":"10B","value":91},{"gate":"21B","value":9},{"gate":"24B","value":1},{"gate":"JC","value":48352},{"gate":"LOCALISER","value":22},{"gate":1,"value":34351},{"gate":2,"value":37855},{"gate":3,"value":38462},{"gate":4,"value":38126},{"gate":5,"value":40089},{"gate":6,"value":39295},{"gate":7,"value":36581},{"gate":8,"value":33908},{"gate":9,"value":31187},{"gate":10,"value":22915},{"gate":11,"value":5164},{"gate":12,"value":9533},{"gate":13,"value":6454},{"gate":14,"value":5003},{"gate":15,"value":1},{"gate":21,"value":19804},{"gate":22,"value":21239},{"gate":23,"value":17779},{"gate":24,"value":15213},{"gate":"-","value":37562}];
var gatePosResult = [];

for(var i = 0; i < gatePos.length; i++) {
    gatePosResult[i] = {};
    for(var key in gatePos[i]) {
        if(gatePos[i].hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            gatePosResult[i][key] = gatePos[i][key];
        }
    }     
    gatePosResult[i].value = null;
    for(var j = 0; j < gatePosValue.length; j++) {
        if(gatePosValue[j].gate === gatePosResult[i].gate) {
            gatePosResult[i].value = gatePosValue[j].value;
            break;
        }
    }
}
console.log(gatePosResult);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `resuce` and `find` like:

```
let result = gatePos.reduce(function(res, obj) {     // for each object obj in gatePos array
    var found = otherArray.find(function(o) {        // check if there is an object in the other array (rename the variable name before use)
        return o.gate == obj.gate;                   // that has the same gate as the object obj
    });
    if(found) {                                      // if we found one
        var newObj = Object.assign({}, obj);         // then create a new object
        newObj.value = found.value;                  // set its value
        res.push(newObj);                            // and add it to the result array
    }
    return res;
}, []);
```

**Note:** I refered to the second array from your question as `otherArray`. Rename the variable name to match the real variable used to hold that array.